# How to get the positions of all matches in a String?

Tags: java, string, match

I have a text document and a query (the query could be more than one word). I want to find the position of all occurrences of the query in the document.

I thought of the `documentText.indexOf(query)` or using regular expression but I could not make it work.

I end up with the following method:

First, I have create a dataType called `QueryOccurrence`

```
public class QueryOccurrence implements Serializable{
  public QueryOccurrence(){}
  private int start;
  private int end;      

  public QueryOccurrence(int nameStart,int nameEnd,String nameText){
    start=nameStart;
    end=nameEnd;        
  }

  public int getStart(){
    return start;
  }

  public int getEnd(){
    return end;
  }

  public void SetStart(int i){
    start=i;
  }

  public void SetEnd(int i){
     end=i;
  }
}
```

Then, I have used this datatype in the following method:

```
    public static List<QueryOccurrence>FindQueryPositions(String documentText, String query){

    // Normalize do the following: lower case, trim, and remove punctuation
    String normalizedQuery = Normalize.Normalize(query);
    String normalizedDocument = Normalize.Normalize(documentText);

    String[] documentWords = normalizedDocument.split(" ");;               
    String[] queryArray = normalizedQuery.split(" ");


    List<QueryOccurrence> foundQueries = new ArrayList();
    QueryOccurrence foundQuery = new QueryOccurrence();

    int index = 0;

    for (String word : documentWords) {            

        if (word.equals(queryArray[0])){
            foundQuery.SetStart(index);
        }

        if (word.equals(queryArray[queryArray.length-1])){
            foundQuery.SetEnd(index);
            if((foundQuery.End()-foundQuery.Start())+1==queryArray.length){

                //add the found query to the list
                foundQueries.add(foundQuery);
                //flush the foundQuery variable to use it again
                foundQuery= new QueryOccurrence();
            }
        }

        index++;
    }
    return foundQueries;
}
```

This method return a list of all occurrence of the query in the document each one with its position.

Could you suggest any easer and faster way to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Comment: This should help:  [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first approach was a good idea, but String.indexOf does not support regular expressions.

Another easier way which uses a similar approach, but in a two step method, is as follows:

```
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(queryPattern);  // insert your pattern here
Matcher m = p.matcher(documentText);
while (m.find()) {
   positions.add(m.start());
}
```

Where positions will hold all the start positions of the matches.

Comment: You will need to regex-escape the query (given as a parameter) to get its pattern. +1, good approach.

Comment: the index in my code was for the words as I tokenised the document by spaces and loop through it to find the match. Your approach gives the index of first letter of the word not the position of the word.  Can Regex be used to find the position of the word instead of the index.