# HighLighting all match words Java

Tags: java, documentlistener

I have a `TextArea` which contains a document. I implemented a `DocumentListener` in order to highlight words that matches in the `TextField`.

What this code does is highlight I single word instead of all matches. i.e: if i try to search the word "move" in the `TextArea`, & there're repeated 3 times that word, this code just highlight the first one and no the rest, I need to highlight all words that matches!

```
public void search() throws BadLocationException //This method makes all logic for highLigh from jtextField into Document(TextArea)
    {
        highLighter.removeAllHighlights();
        String s = textField.getText();

        if(s.length() <= 0)
        {
            labelMessage("Nothing to search for..");
            return; //go out from this "if statement!".
        }

        String content = textArea.getText();
        int index = content.indexOf(s, 0); //"s" = the whole document, 0 = means that was found(match) or -1 if no match(no found is return -1)

        if(index >= 0) //match found
        {
            int end = index + s.length();
            highLighter.addHighlight(index, end, highlighterPainter);
            textArea.setCaretPosition(end);
            textField.setBackground(entryBgColor);
            labelMessage("'" + s + "' found. Press ESC to end search");
        }

    }

    void labelMessage(String msm)
    {
        statusLabel.setText(msm);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            search();
        } catch (BadLocationException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You search once, why do you expect it to find multiple matches?

Comment: According to your code it will show only first occurrence, for more you need to get other indexes by matching others

Comment: https://shekhargulati.com/2010/05/04/finding-all-the-indexes-of-a-whole-word-in-a-given-string-using-java/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326872/how-to-get-the-positions-of-all-matches-in-a-string

Comment: @Idos I need to find multiples matches cause if the user wanna find the word "Hank" & in the document there're 5 Hanks i wanna give him the possiblility of the others matches too no just the first one..

Comment: @vickyexpert exactly, i need other indexes, but i wanna make it automatically, without have to reference index by index, cause if in the TextArea there're 10 times the same word, i can't make all those references.. there're a way of making it without reference one by one?

Comment: check my answer if it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code if it help you,

```
    String content = textArea.getText();

    while(content.lastIndexOf(s) >= 0)
    {
        int index = content.lastIndexOf(s);
        int end = index + s.length;

        highLighter.addHighlight(index, end, highlighterPainter);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(end);
        textField.setBackground(entryBgColor);
        labelMessage("'" + s + "' found. Press ESC to end search");

        content = content.substring(0, index - 1);
    }
```

Comment: what " i " vriable means? where is declared?

Comment: it's index sorry change it by index

Answer (score 0):

```
final String s = textField.getText();

String content = textArea.getText();
boolean  b = content.contains(s);  
while (b) {
    int start = content.indexOf(stringToMatch);
    int end = start + s.length() -1;

    // Write your lighlighting code here

    if (content.length() >= end ) {
      content = content.substring(end, content.length()) ;
      b = content.contains(s);
    } else {
      b = false;
    }
}
```

Does this help?